# How to upload many Android projects in the same github repository?

Tags: android-studio, github

I have some related Android projects that I want to upload to github to be all in 1 repository the same as in this picture [image: this picture], I tried to upload the projects manually by drag and drop on github website but it failed to upload showing me this message "Yowza, that’s a lot of files. Try again with fewer than 100 files." as shown in the picture below [image: this picture]
Please list all possible solutions and note that I'm not familiar with git command line. If it's not possible please list other alternatives to group related projects in one place on github. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I know how to do it.
1- open github website and go to the desired repo.
2- click add file and then upload files.
3- open your Android project in explorer.
4- delete the build folder which is inside the app folder in your project.
5- drag your project and drop it in github upload window.
for detailed steps you can follow [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SXkemWsZdec)

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, best way to do so is by uploading fewer files (e.g. 50).
After that, you can then upload the remaining (e.g. 50) files.